# Android: "Camera.takePicture failed" Exception

Tags: android, exception, camera

I'm experiencing an odd problem. I'm doing my testing on an HTC EVO. I have written a demo camera application targeting 2.2 and almost everything works correctly. The problem is that after taking three or four pictures, the application crashes and gives me the following messages:

```
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): takePicture(479)
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): val_ril_status = 0,val_wimax_status = 0,val_hotspot_status = 0,val_low_temp_limit = 10.000000,val_batt_temp = 29.799999,val_low_temp_limit = 15,val_batt_cap  = 96
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): FLASHLIGHT is ENABLED
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): stopPreviewInternal E: 1
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): cancelAutoFocusInternal E
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): cancelAutoFocusInternal X: 0
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): deinitPreview E
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): launch_watchdog_thread:
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): watchdog_thread_id = 369048
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 35, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4153f000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 35, reg = 1 buffer = 0x415bf000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 35, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4163f000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 35, reg = 1 buffer = 0x416bf000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4331d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4351d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4371d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4391d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x43b1d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x43d1d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x43f1d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): register_buf: camfd = 38, reg = 1 buffer = 0x4411d000
I/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): deinitPreview X
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): stopPreviewInternal X: 0
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw E: raw size=3264x2448
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw: raw ration = 0.750000, display size=768x432
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw: thumbnail_width=768, thumbnail_height=576, thumbnail_buffer_size=663552
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): native_access_parm: fd 24, type 1, length 32
D/mm-camera-ov8810_u(   64): andy cam_mode_sel 0
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw: initializing mRawHeap.
E/MemoryHeapBase(   64): error opening /dev/pmem_camera: No such file or directory
E/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): failed to construct master heap for pmem pool /dev/pmem_camera
E/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw X failed with pmem_camera, trying with pmem_adsp
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): frame_thread X
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): watchdog_thread_id = 369048
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): release_watchdog_thread: frame_thread_released = 1
E/MemoryHeapBase(   64): mmap(fd=38, size=11988992) failed (Invalid argument)
E/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): failed to construct master heap for pmem pool /dev/pmem_adsp
E/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw X: error initializing mRawHeap
E/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): initRaw failed.  Not taking picture.
D/AndroidRuntime( 2650): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:503)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at spikes.cameraSpike03.MainActivity.takePicture(MainActivity.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at spikes.cameraSpike03.MainActivity.access$3(MainActivity.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at spikes.cameraSpike03.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2650):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  107):   Force finishing activity spikes.cameraSpike03/.MainActivity
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): void* watchdog(void*), frame_thread_released = 1, cnt = 0
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): void* watchdog(void*), exit, frame_thread_released=1
D/QualcommCameraHardware(   64): void release_watchdog_thread(): pthread_join succeeded on watchdog.
```

Could this be a memory management problem?

Below is all the code I'm using.

[AndroidManifest.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="spikes.cameraSpike03"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
</manifest>
```

[main.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/svCameraView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#3000" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
  <Button android:id="@+id/btnCapture" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="capture" />
  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkAutofocus" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Autofocus" />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[MainActivity.java]

```
package spikes.cameraSpike03;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
 private static final String LOG_LINE = "---------------------------------";

 private Camera _camera;
 private boolean _previewIsRunning = false;

 private SurfaceView _svCameraView;
 private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
 private Button _btnCapture;
 private CheckBox _chkAutofocus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _svCameraView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.svCameraView);

        _surfaceHolder = _svCameraView.getHolder();
        _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        _surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        _chkAutofocus = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkAutofocus);

        _btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        _btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(_camera != null){
     //Decide whether or not to use autofocus
     if(_chkAutofocus.isChecked()){
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Preparing to take the picture using autofocus...");

      _camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "_camera.autoFocus.onAutoFocus(...) entered.");

        takePicture();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "_camera.autoFocus.onAutoFocus(...) finished.");
       }
      });
     }
     else{
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Preparing to take the picture without autofocus...");

      takePicture();
     }
    }
   }
  });
    }

    private void takePicture(){
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "takePicture() entered.");

     _camera.takePicture(_shutterCallback, null, _jpegCallback);
  _previewIsRunning = false;

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "takePicture() finished.");
    }

    private ShutterCallback _shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onShutter() {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "_shutterCallback.onShutter() called.");
  }
 };

 private PictureCallback _jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "_jpegCallback.onPictureTaken() called.");

   _camera.startPreview();
   _previewIsRunning = true;
  }
 };

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
  if(_previewIsRunning){
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "About to stop preview...");

   _camera.stopPreview();

   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Stopped preview.");
  }

  try{
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "About to set up camera parameters...");

   Camera.Parameters parameters = _camera.getParameters();

   //Get the optimal preview size so we don't get an exception when setting the parameters 
   List<Size> supportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
   Size optimalPreviewSize = CameraUtil.getOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);

   parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
   parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
   parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

   _camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

   _camera.setParameters(parameters);

   _camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

   Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Finished setting up camera parameters.");
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
  }

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "About to start preview...");

  _camera.startPreview();
  _previewIsRunning = true;

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Started preview.");
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  _camera = Camera.open();
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Tearing down camera because surface was destroyed...");

  _camera.stopPreview();
  _previewIsRunning = false;
  _camera.release();

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Finished tearing down camera because surface was destroyed.");
 }

 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "About to set request orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT...");

  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

  Log.d(LOG_TAG, LOG_LINE + "Successfully set request orientation to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.");
 }
}
```

[CameraUtil.java]

```
package spikes.cameraSpike03;

import java.util.List;

import android.hardware.Camera.Size;

public class CameraUtil {
 private CameraUtil(){}

 /**
  * Returns a Size object containing the dimensions for an optimal preview size for the current hardware.
  * This code is based on that found at: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html
  * 
  * @param supportedSizes
  * A list of Size objects representing all the known preview sizes supported by this hardware.
  * 
  * @param w
  * The surface width.
  * 
  * @param h
  * The surface height.
  * 
  * @return
  * Returns a Size object containing the dimensions for an optimal preview size for the current hardware.
  */
 public static Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> supportedSizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (supportedSizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : supportedSizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : supportedSizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Alright, further testing seems to indicate that these problems only happen when I use auto-focus. Hmmm....

Comment: I have same problem. I tried to close params. But nothing changed. I think its about memory, too.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167492/2968400

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167492/2968400

Answer (score 8):

I also had the similar issue. later i found startPreview is very important.

`_camera.startPreview()` is very important  before the takePicutre  checkout the point 5 and 6 in this link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html