# Camera.takePicture() gives no callback

Tags: android, callback, camera

**SOLVED**, SEE COMMENT ---
I never get a callback from Camera.takePicture(), I see that in logcat.
What is missing? How do I make takePicture()... take a picture?!
Most of this is directly from Android developers camera guide. I want to take pictures programmatically without any preview or user action. Using the built in camera app works fine. SDK 16.

And in the manifest I do have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="true" />
```

The code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bTake =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_take);
    boolean boo = safeCameraOpen(camId);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    bTake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

             mCamera.takePicture(shutter, null, null, picture);

             Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "After takePicture");               
         }
     });

}// END onCreate 


/* Camera operations */

private ShutterCallback shutter = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "onShutter");
    }
};

private PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "onPicTaken");
    }
};


/* Starting up and closing down*/

private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;
    try {
        releaseCamera();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        ((Camera) mCamera).release();
        mCamera = null;
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "cam released");
    }
}}
```

Comment: Problem solved! One needs mCamera.startPreview() for mCamera.takePicture() to work. Even if one has no other use for previews.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: "Camera.takePicture failed" Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830772/android-camera-takepicture-failed-exception)

Comment: I didn't get any exception. But anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mCamera.takePicture(shutter, picture, picture);
```